# IIS7 features are missing

Tags: iis

I have two computers, home and work. The home computer runs Windows 7 Home Premium and work computer has Windows 7 Professional. Both have IIS7 installed on.

On the left hand side of the image you can see my home computer iis features on/off screen and on the right hand side my work computer's iis features. Sory for my home computer language is turkish but I matched corresponding items in english.

My question is why left side has only 4 security features whereas right side has 8. How can I add missing fetures?

[image]

Comment: This appears to be off-topic for this programming forum. But you might want to look at [Available Web Server (IIS) Role Services in IIS 7.5](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753473.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIS on Windows Home Premium edition is limited comparing to Windows Professional. For example, windows authentication (almost any domain related stuff) is not supported. That's why you see different feature sets.